# Match Array Value with input field inside nested while Loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, while-loop

It's a really silly problem.i don't know how i get this but i get.
i have a array and i wants to match array values with checkbox which came from while loop.So how is it possible.

```
                  //Array that i want to match with checkbox
                  $filter = explode(',', $getproduct->specification_filter);
                  <table class="table" style="background-color: white;">
                      <tbody>
                        <?php
                          while($fch = $allfilter->fetch_array()){
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                          <th><?=$fch[2]?></th>
                          <?php 
                          $sqlbv="SELECT * FROM product_filter where idd='$fch[4]'";
                          $resultbv=$conn->query($sqlbv);
                          while($rowbv = $resultbv->fetch_array()){
                        ?>
                          <td>
                            <label class="ckbox ckbox-danger">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="<?=$rowbv[0]?>" name="pfilter[]">
                                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?=$rowbv[3]?></span>
                              </label>
                          </td>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Now i wants to check Checkbox field if `$filter`arrays value match with checkbox value. So how can i do that ?

Comment: You mean to say, if `$rowbv[0]` will be available in `$filter` array then you want to check the checkbox?

Comment: yes. i try to use foreach in input type check box.is it good ?

Comment: Sorry, but am I correct in saying that you want to check if the checkbox value selected is a valid entry? Is that right?

Comment: nope @SeanKonig.  if $rowbv[0] is available in $filter array then i want to check the checkbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since your `$filter` is an array use `in_array`

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="<?=$rowbv[0]?>" <?=  in_array($rowbv[0], $filter)? 'checked':''  ?> name="pfilter[]">
```

for more details see [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Answer (score 0):

Just use in_array() to check this. If its true and marked checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?=$rowbv[0]?>" name="pfilter[]" <?php echo in_array($rowbv[0],$filter) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';?>>
```

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

In input checkbox, you can check adding attribute 'checked'.

For that, you can write

```
< input type="checkbox" < ?=($rowbv[0] ? 'checked' : '')?> name="pfilter[]"/>
```

else

```
< input type="checkbox" < ?php echo $rowbv[0] ? 'checked' : '';?> name="pfilter[]"/>
```